# Defined error message in the PHP

Tags: php

How do I "make" error messages in best practices? Right now I just have `$error = '';` and then just a lot of if(){}s that do `.= 'Message<br>'`, and then `if (!empty($error)) { echo $error; }`, which I assume is a terrible thing.

Comment: You have to be more specific, what do you use that error for?

Comment: Yes it is. However as you can imagine (you already see all these ifs here and there), there are many answers to that question. Also it would be good to know in which context these errors are. Mabye with forms? Have you taken a look with a form component like in Pear or with a Framework like ins Symfony2?

Comment: I need to just know a generic way to do it that is better than "add a line to a string" -- they can be anywhere from "$var is unset" to "email field is blank".. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show error to user. I usually use an array.

```
$success = true;
$messages = array();
if($something_wrong == true){
   $success = false;
   $messages[] = 'something wrong';
}

if($morething_wrong == true){
   $success = false;
   $messages[] = 'more thing wrong';
}

if(!$success){
   foreach($messages as $message){
      echo $message.'<br />';
   }
}
```

Basically if things goes wrong, I'll always assign the message as the new last component of $messages. In the end of execution, I show all of the messages.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it:

```
function err($err){
    switch($err){
        case 0: $message.="brain fried"; break;  // comment if you want
        case 1: $message.="head ache"; break;
        case 2: $message.="segment fault big time"; break;
    }
return $message;
}
```

And

```
if (something is wrong){$message=err(3);}
```

Just a way to group things all together.